# Mint Ethernet connection works for few seconds then stops

Tags: networking, linux-mint, ethernet

I'm using Mint 18.1. In brief, my problem is when I try to connect to the internet via Ethernet.

### What is it?

I plug in the cable, it gets a valid IP address(DHCP) and then I run `ping google.com`. Just a few packets sent and then it stops. the output:

[image: Output of ping]

I tried the following solution I've found on the web but it didn't work for me:

- Set MTU to a higher value(8192, 9000, ...)
- I talked to the network admin, he told me that it would be your laptop problem.

### Some relevant information

```
>> lspci
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98M [GeForce G 105M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)

>> ifconfig ensp4s0
enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:5a:b3:dc:45  
          inet addr:172.16.205.69  Bcast:172.16.205.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2c96:e0a6:ed5a:84c2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:8192  Metric:1
          RX packets:123350 errors:0 dropped:30 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:45440 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:14432278 (14.4 MB)  TX bytes:6014453 (6.0 MB)

>> netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.205.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp4s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 enp4s0
172.16.205.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp4s0

>> uname -a
Linux Hadi 4.4.0-98-generic #121-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 14:24:03 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```